# Adjacency list representation of a directed graph using c++ vector

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-list

I'm a newcomer. I'm facing a problem with c++ vector and its iterator. I have tried to represent a adjacency list of a directed graph but failed. Here is my code: `

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Node,Edge,node1,node2,cost;
    vector<int>nodes[100],costs[100];
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    cout<<"Enter numbers of nodes: "<<endl;
    cin>>Node;
    cout<<"Enter numbers of edges: "<<endl;
    cin>>Edge;
    for(int i=0;i<Edge;i++){
        cout<<i+1<<"th edge's Node1: ";
        cin>>node1;
        cout<<i+1<<"th edge's Node2: ";
        cin>>node2;
        cout<<"Cost from "<<node1<<" to"<<node2<<": ";
        cin>>cost;
        cout<<endl;
        nodes[node1].push_back(node2);
        costs[node1].push_back(cost);
    }
    for(it=nodes.begin();it<nodes.end();it++){
        for(int i=0;i<nodes[it].size();i++){
            cout<<nodes[it][i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: How did it fail? If you've encountered a compiler error, include it in your question. If you've encountered a runtime error, include it in your question. If you didn't get the results you've expected, add both the expected and actual results in your question. If your cat is on fire, call the fire brigade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have told us about the compilation error that you've encountered.

Trying to compile your code immediately shows an inconsistency in the loop:

```
for(it=nodes.begin();it<nodes.end();it++)
```

and on the following uses of `it`. In fact you use `it` in indexes, as if it were an `int` .  But you've declared it as an iterator:

```
vector<int>::iterator it;  // you say it is an iterator that iterates through integers in ONE vector
```

Inexed access and iterators are two different concepts.

**Solution 1: use indexes**

Just use an index of type `int` (or better `size_t`):

```
...
const size_t maxnodes=100; 
vector<int>nodes[maxnodes],costs[maxnodes];
// + remove the definition of it
...
for(size_t it=0;it<maxnodes;it++) {
...
```

**Solution 2: use iterators, but correctly**

Let the compiler define the right type for the iterator, and then dereference the iterator (i.e. handle it as if it were a pointer):

```
// remove the definition of the it at the begin of main
...  // rest of code unchanged except for the loop
for(auto it=begin(nodes);it!=end(nodes);it++){  // attention at the condition
    for(int i=0;i<it->size();i++){
        cout<<(*it)[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Here a [live demo](http://ideone.com/66yDVA)

**Solution 3: use the confortable range for**

Forget about the iterators and let the compiler handle the job for you:

```
for(auto& n : nodes) {  // note the &, to get the original element and not a clone of it
    for(int i=0;i<n.size();i++){
        cout<<n[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout <<endl;
}
```

Here another [live demo](http://ideone.com/IIwoCJ).

You will immediately realize that you could as well use the range for to handle the inner loop:

```
    for(int& target : n) {  // when reading the code outloud, say " in " instead of ":"
        cout<<target<<" ";
    }
```

**Final remarks**

You should always verify the user's data input, especially to ensure that it's in the valid range if you are using it as index.

Comment: Thanks to u a lot for your suggetion. :)